# Function to generate random 8 Character Password

Tags: vb.net

I have this function in vb that had seemed to be working before to generate an 8 character password but now generates the same password for each user who registers to the website. I am unsure as to where I have went wrong as I have not fiddled with this piece of code (code was not written by me)? Any help would be appreciated.

```
function generatePassword()
  Dim i, newPassword
  newPassword = ""
  For i = 1 to 3
    newPassword = newPassword & Mid("ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ",randomInRange(1,24),1)
  Next
  For i = 4 to 7
    newPassword = newPassword & Mid("23456789",randomInRange(1,8),1)
  Next
  'For i = 1 to 8
  '  newPassword = newPassword & Mid("ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789",randomInRange(1,32),1)
  'Next
  generatePassword = newPassword
end function

function randomInRange(lo,hi)
  randomInRange =(Int((hi - lo + 1) * rnd + lo))
end function

Dim newPassword = generatePassword()

            Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO Student(" & _
                             "StudentNo," & _
                             "Surname," & _
                             "FirstName," & _
                             "MiddleName," & _
                             "Gender," & _
                             "Pathway," & _
                             "[Level]," & _
                             "QubEmail," & _
                             "[Password]," & _
                             "HomeEmail," & _
                             "MobilePhone," & _
                             "HomeTown," & _
                             "PlacementYear," & _
                             "Status," & _
                             "DateEdited," & _
                             "HomePhone) " & _
                            "VALUES " & _
                            "( " & _
                             "'" & StudentNo.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'," & _
                             "'" & Surname.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'," & _
                             "'" & Forename.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'," & _
                             "'" & MiddleName.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'," & _
                            "'" & ddlGender.SelectedValue & "'," & _
                            "'" & ddlPathway.SelectedValue & "'," & _
                            "'" & ddlLevel.SelectedValue & "'," & _
                            "'" & QUBEmail.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'," & _
                            "'" & newPassword & "'," & _
                             "'" & HomeEmail.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'," & _
                            "'" & MobileNo.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'," & _
                            "'" & HomeTown.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'," & _
                            "" & PlacementYear & "," & _
                            "'Seeking Placement'," & _
                            " GETDATE() ," & _
                             "'" & HomeNo.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "' " & _
                            ")"


            Dim addStudent As OleDbDataReader = Database.DoSQLReturnDataReader(strSql)
            addStudent.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any code that is updating the `rnd` variable. This needs to update each time you call `randomInRange` to get different passwords.

I would suggest that you change `randomInRange` entirely to make it run more cleanly.

This is what you need to do:

```
Private rnd As Random = new Random()
Function randomInRange(lo As Integer, hi As Integer) As Integer
    Return rnd.Next(lo, hi + 1)
End Function
```

Making this change produces random passwords.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably talk to the person that wrote the code if you're not a programmer yourself. Nevertheless, a `Rnd` is really not random, but only a sofisticated mathematical equation using a seed to calculate its value.

This seed is set to the time when the program runs. Without any involvement, the seed will stay the same which means that all randoms will actually be the same value; use [Randomize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt.aspx) at each `generatePassword()`.

```
Function generatePassword()
    Randomize()

    /.../
End Function
```

Comment: The `Randomize()` call has nothing to do with the `Random` class. They are two totally unrelated bits of code.

Comment: @Enigmativity I was thinking of the `Rnd()` function. My bad.

Comment: @Enigmativity Since the OP's provided code originally contained the Rnd() function, and not the Random class, I don't see how your down-vote, or criticism was called for. You should consider un-downvoting this answer, because Randomize is indeed relevant to the RND function. Now with that being said, I still think the Random class is a better approach.

Comment: @PaulIshak - The OP doesn't have `Rnd()` in the question, nevertheless this answer has `Random` and that just perpetuates the misunderstanding that `Randomize()` somehow relates to `Random`. I understand your point, but it's past the two hour time limit to change my down-vote, so I can't unless this answer is edited.